# Easiest way to set past/future date in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, zoneddatetime

I have a solution for setting future/past date Java 8, but I would like to know if there is a cleaner way.
I have a method in which one of the argument is of type `ZonedDateTime`.

I am extracting the time, converting to milliseconds and subtracting that from present now.

```
void setFuturePastDate(ZonedDateTime dateTime) {
    long diffInSeconds = ZonedDateTime.now().toEpochSecond() 
        - dateTime.toEpochSecond();
    Duration durationInSeconds = Duration.ofSeconds(diffInSeconds);
    Instant instantInSeconds = now.minusSeconds(durationInSeconds); 
    Clock clock = Clock.fixed(instantInSeconds, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(clock)); // - I have a past date
```

In Joda it was simple:

```
setCurrentMillisSystem(long)
```

and wherever we access `new DateTime()` it will give the date set.

Is there a cleaner way in Java 8 ?

Comment: sorry for that, will keep it in mind. accepted the answer by Ole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void setFuturePastDate(ZonedDateTime dateTime) {
    Clock clock = Clock.fixed(dateTime.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(clock)); // - I have a past date 
}
```

This method prints the same `ZonedDateTime` as I passed in (provided it has the default zone).

Comment: Yes,Best way.....

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you want:

```
void setFuturePastDate(LocalDateTime dateTime){
    final LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    final Duration duration = Duration.between(now, dateTime);
    final LocalDateTime mirrored;
    if(duration.isNegative()){
        mirrored = now.minus(duration);
    } else {
        mirrored = now.plus(duration);
    }

    System.out.println(mirrored);
}
```

This *mirrors* the dateTime around the `now()`. E.g: 5 days in the past becomes 5 days in the future.